# on scroll loads incorrectly with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

The data is correclty loaded, but I want it to load when I reach the end of the window not every time I scroll, the code works as I want in chrome and FF but not in IE8

```
 if ((document.body.clientHeight +  document.body.scrollTop) >= document.body.offsetHeight){  
//load
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution thyat worked for all browsers including IE 8

```
 var win_h = (self.innerHeight) ? self.innerHeight : document.body.clientHeight;    // 

  gets window height

  // gets current vertical scrollbar position
  var scrl_pos = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

  // if scrollbar reaches to bottom
  if (document.body.scrollHeight <= (scrl_pos + win_h)) {
  //load
 }
```